# Trying to play sound effects using XNA

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm writing my first app for windows phone, which will be a sound board, using XNa's soundeffect object.

The project is a Windows phone Silverlight and Xna Application c#

I got some sample code from the book, 101 phone 7 apps.
The linbe to load in the sound gives me a 
 "the type StreamResourceInfo namespace could not be found"

StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Audio/cowbell.wav", UriKind.Relative));

the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;


namespace SlXnaApp4
{
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    SoundEffect cowbell;

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        // Load sound file

        StreamResourceInfo info = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Audio/cowbell.wav", UriKind.Relative));

        // create xna sound
        cowbell = SoundEffect.FromStream(info);

        // Sub to per frame call back
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;

        // requred for xna sound effects to work
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();

        // testb sound
        cowbell.Play();

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Xna.Framework.FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
    }




    // Simple button Click event handler to take us to the second page
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you added a reference to `System.Windows`?

Comment: `System.Windows` is always referenced by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a using directive for [System.Windows.Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resources.streamresourceinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
using System.Windows.Resources;
```